# Nokia JavaScript API Map panning issue on WP8 IE

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

I have a strange map interaction issue with Nokia Here JavaScript API map with the Internet Explorer of Windows Phone 8. So far I've tried Nokia Lumia 820 and HTC 8X and both have the same issue. It does not happen on desktop browsers.

It seems that only map interactions (such as panning) or overlay control buttons (such as zoom and map mode selection) work for each page load. The firstly used feature works while the other does not. When map is panned first it seems like map gets the events when trying to tap controls.

Below is the basic map with components example code from developer.here.com. The same issue happens with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9; IE=10" />
    <base href="http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/getting-started/basic-map-with-components.html" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Nokia Maps API for JavaScript Example: Basic map with components</title>
    <meta name="description" content="How to get a basic map with all UI components enabled"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="basiccomponents, getting started, basic map, components"/>
    <!-- For scaling content for mobile devices, setting the viewport to the width of the device-->
    <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <!-- Styling for example container (NoteContainer & Logger)  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/templates/js/exampleHelpers.css"/>
    <!-- By default we add ?with=all to load every package available, it's better to change this parameter to your use case. Options ?with=maps|positioning|places|placesdata|directions|datarendering|all -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript for example container (NoteContainer & Logger)  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/templates/js/exampleHelpers.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html {
        overflow:hidden;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      }

      #mapContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
    <div id="uiContainer"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="exampleJsSource">
/*  Setup authentication app_id and app_code 
*   WARNING: this is a demo-only key
*   please register for an Evaluation, Base or Commercial key for use in your app.
*   Just visit http://developer.here.com/get-started for more details. Thank you!
*/
nokia.Settings.set("app_id", "DemoAppId01082013GAL"); 
nokia.Settings.set("app_code", "AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg");
// Use staging environment (remove the line for production environment)
nokia.Settings.set("serviceMode", "cit");

// Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
// Create a map inside the map container DOM node
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
  // initial center and zoom level of the map
  center: [52.51, 13.4],
  zoomLevel: 10,
  components: [
    // ZoomBar provides a UI to zoom the map in & out
    new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(), 
    // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
    new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
    // Creates UI to easily switch between street map satellite and terrain mapview modes
    new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),
    // Creates a toggle button to show/hide traffic information on the map
    new nokia.maps.map.component.Traffic(),
    // Creates a toggle button to show/hide public transport lines on the map
    new nokia.maps.map.component.PublicTransport(),
    // Creates a toggle button to enable the distance measurement tool
    new nokia.maps.map.component.DistanceMeasurement(),
    // Shows a min-map in the bottom right corner of the map
    new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(),
    /* Shows a scale bar in the bottom right corner of the map depicting
     * ratio of a distance on the map to the corresponding distance in the real world
     * in either kilometers or miles
     */ 
    new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar(),
    /* Positioning will show a set "map to my GPS position" UI button
     * Note: this component will only be visible if W3C geolocation API
     * is supported by the browser and if you agree to share your location.
     * If you location can not be found the positioning button will reset
     * itself to its initial state
     */
    new nokia.maps.positioning.component.Positioning(),
    // Add ContextMenu component so we get context menu on right mouse click / long press tap
    new nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu(),
    // ZoomRectangle component adds zoom rectangle functionality to the map
    new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomRectangle()
  ]
});

/* We create a UI notecontainer for example description
 * NoteContainer is a UI helper function and not part of the Nokia Maps API
 * See exampleHelpers.js for implementation details 
 */
var noteContainer = new NoteContainer({
  id: "basicMapWithComponentsUi",
  parent: document.getElementById("uiContainer"),
  title: "Basic map example with components",
  content:
    '<p>This example shows how to create a basic pannable map with a  ' +
    'map type selector, scalebar, public transport button, ' +
    'mini map, positioning and a zoombar.</p>'
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* you mixed up HTML 5 and HTML 4 meta tag declarations.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately fixing it doesn't fix the issue.